# How can I show as an option to open my custom iOS camera editing application for capture picture from any web browser or third party application?

Tags: ios

I want to show my application as a suggestion in document picker popup.

I am using intents extension to show my application as a suggestion in document picker popup but that is not useful for me. So please help me .

I create a single application related to capture image from camera and add some editing functionality.

So, My question is that. I want to show my application as a suggestion application to capture image from any browser camera click option or any third party image capture application for capturing and editing image from my application.

Answer (score 0):

You can do these things using photo editing extension. See the following posts

https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/extensions/photo-editing/

https://www.appcoda.com/photo-editing-extensions/

https://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Creating_an_iOS_8_Photo_Editing_Extension